# subprocess call behaves differently on different Windows installations

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have two very similar Windows 7 Enterprise machines.

But when I run this piece of code (python 2.73) it works on one of them but not the other.

```
command = [
        'artifact',
        'cp',
        source,
        target
    ]

artifact_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I get this error message:

```
    artifact_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The "artifact" command that I am trying to run with some arguments is just an in-house developed java command line tool. It is on PATH for both machines and it works fine to run the same command manually.

```
C:\Jenkins\3\workspace>where artifact
C:\Binaries\artifact-cli\artifact
C:\Binaries\artifact-cli\artifact.bat
```

But when I try to run it via python scripts and the subprocess command, it fails on one of the machines. 
If I add "shell=True" to the subprocess command. Then it works on both machines.

I have been trying to compare the setup for both of these machines trying to find some difference that could help to explain why it works on one but not the other. But so far I have come up empty.

I really would like to avoid using "shell=True" and as far as I understand I shouldn't have to for an operation like this.

Question is. What in Windows could cause this difference?

Comment: Run `where artifact` and note the file extension. `Popen` calls WINAPI `CreateProcess`, which only supports ".exe" as a default extension. `CreateProcess` runs PE executable files. It also runs batch scripts (.bat or .cmd file extension) via the shell that's defined by the `ComSpec` environment variable, which defaults to cmd.exe. For other file types and file extensions we need `shell=True`, for which CMD will fall back on `ShellExecuteEx` to open the file.

Comment: Updated the post with the output of "where artifact". The output is the same on both machines. `ComSpec` environment variable is also the same on both machines, `ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: With `shell=True`, you're running "artifact.bat". You should know from my first comment that `CreateProcess` will run this batch script without `shell=True` only if you use the full name with the .bat file extension. Either use "artifact.bat" explicitly, or look at its contents to try to implement it directly.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for the clarification, but it still doesn't explain why it works on another Windows machine by just calling "artifact" without the .bat extension and "shell=False". Is there something else that can be done to achieve that result?

Comment: That depends on what "C:\Binaries\artifact-cli\artifact" is on each system. Figuring out the difference will probably also require reading "artifact.bat" to see what it does.

Comment: `"C:\Binaries\artifact-cli\artifact"` is a bash shell script.  The "artifact" script is the same on both systems. "artifact.bat" is also the same on both systems.

Comment: What's the content of the batch script, i.e. the output of `type "C:\Binaries\artifact-cli\artifact.bat"`? Determining what the batch script runs when you use `shell=True` will probably help with understanding what's happening with `shell=False`.

Comment: Also, please confirm that using "artifact.bat" works with `shell=False` on both systems. It should.

Comment: I tested with "artifact.bat" and it works when shell=False, at least on the system that has been giving me problems. I can test the same thing on the other system as well as soon as I get access to it.

Comment: The content of the batch script is this:
`@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar "%~dp0\artifact-management-0.0.12-jar-with-dependencies.jar" --scriptName "%0" %*`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't explain how just "artifact" was working on the one system, since the only command with that name is a bash shell script, which shouldn't work in this context. However, it does demonstrate how to run the jar file directly via `java_exe = os.path.join(os.environ['JAVA_HOME'], 'bin', 'java.exe')`. In the batch script, `"%0"` is the full script path, and `"%~dp0"` is its directory ([d]rive and [p]ath), i.e. "C:\Binaries\artifact-cli".

Comment: Yes and it is exactly that explanation I would like to have. I am contemplating to change the implementation to call "artifact.bat" when on Windows, but it would be nice to also understand why I see this difference in these two machines.

Comment: The system where "artifact" works without `shell=True` is the exception that defies expected behavior. Definitely a special case is required for Windows -- either to use "artifact.bat" explicitly or to use `shell=True`. In terms of implementation they're nearly the same. The main difference is that with `shell=True` and the file extension omitted, you're relying on CMD to look for the file with the extensions listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable, so typically it will find "artifact.exe" and "artifact.com", if they exist, before "artifact.bat".

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Even if I still don't know exactly why the system behaves like it does, I at least know more about how Windows is supposed to work :-).